# applying methods to single elements in an array - jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created an array of elements called `$images` (all the elements in the `hidden` class.)  Then when I try to apply *any* method to just *one* element in the array, I get a `$images[1].attr is not a function` error.  However, when I try `$images.attr('id')` for example without specifying the index of the array, it works but gives me the result for the first element in the array only.

```
$images = $(".hidden");
alert($images[1].attr('id'));
```

What's going here and how can I apply methods to single elements in an array?  By the way, I'm certain there are at least two elements in the array as I tested it for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want still to have a jQuery object, rather than retrieving a native DOM element object, you need to use the [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq) function.  This gets an element at a position in the array and returns it wrapped in the jQuery object, so you can do jQuery operations on it.

So:

```
$images.eq(1).attr('id');
```

If you only want the DOM element, you can use the square bracket notation or the [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get) method. You can then look up a DOM property directly:

```
$images[1].id;  // is the same as
$images.get(1).id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use .eq, like so:

```
$images = $(".hidden");
alert($images.eq(1).attr('id'));
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

`$images[1]` does not return a jQuery object, it is returning a dom element.

you want `$($images[1]).attr('id')`

Answer (score 1):

The extra methods jQuery decorates the result array with are not present in the elements themselves. To get a specific element, you can use the `eq` selector or method:

```
$images = $(".hidden");
alert($images.eq(1).attr('id'));
```

or

```
$image = $(".hidden:eq(1)");
alert($image.attr('id'));
```

Comment: Yes, though it would be good to note that the selector is much the slower option.